# Testing a controller with a form of String and file upload in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, file-upload, automated-tests, spring-boot-test, mockmvc

I am creating a website to upload recipes, and I am trying to write tests for the create recipe controller. My form contains many fields, such as Recipe Title and Recipe Description. However, it also contains recipe images, where a user can upload either 0, 1, or mulitple images. When I am running the controller in the app it works as it should. However, I am now trying to write a test for it, and I am unable to upload the images.

How do I create a test suite where in one case, I am uploading no images, in another I am uploading just one image, and another where I am uploading mulitple?

This is my recipe form:

```
package FamilyFusion.rnr.controller.forms;

import FamilyFusion.rnr.utils.DoubleCheck.DoubleCheck;
import FamilyFusion.rnr.utils.FileExtensionCheck.FileExtensionCheck;
import FamilyFusion.rnr.utils.IntegerCheck.IntegerCheck;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RecipeForm {

    @NotEmpty(message = "Recipe must have a title")
    private String title;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Recipe must have a description")
    private String description;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Recipe must have servings")
    @IntegerCheck(message = "Servings must be a whole number above {minValue}", checkMinValue = true, minValue = 1)
    private String servings;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Recipe must have an owner")
    private String recipeOwner;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Recipe must have at least 1 tag")
    @Valid
    private List<TagRow> tags = new ArrayList<>();

    @NotEmpty(message = "Recipe must have ingredients")
    @Valid
    private List<IngredientRow> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();

    @NotEmpty(message = "Recipe must have instructions")
    @Valid
    private List<InstructionRow> instructions = new ArrayList<>();

    @FileExtensionCheck(message = "Invalid file type. Only Images are allowed", allowedExtension = "image/")
    private MultipartFile[] imageRoutes = new MultipartFile[0];

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class IngredientRow {
        @NotEmpty(message = "Ingredient name cannot be empty")
        private String name;
        @NotEmpty(message = "Ingredient amount cannot be empty")
        @DoubleCheck(message = "Ingredient amount must be a number above {minValue}", minValue = 1)
        private String amount;
        @NotEmpty(message = "Ingredient unit cannot be empty")
        private String unit;
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class InstructionRow {
        @NotEmpty(message = "Instruction cannot be empty")
        private String instruction;
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class TagRow {
        @NotEmpty(message = "Tag cannot be empty")
        private String name;
    }

}
```

This is my controller for craete recipe:

```
    /**
     * Processing the recipeForm to try and save it in the db.
     *
     * @param recipeForm    - the form the user filled out with all the information needed for the recipe
     * @param bindingResult - where the results of the @Valid is stored. If there are errors, the page will be reloaded with the corresponding message
     * @param model         - the way all the needed information is sent to the front-end
     * @param principal     - used to get information from the logged-in user
     * @return - the name of the html page that is being loaded after finishing everything
     */
    @PostMapping("/createRecipe")
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public String createRecipe(@Valid @ModelAttribute("recipe") RecipeForm recipeForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, Principal principal) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
            model.addAttribute("recipe", recipeForm);
            model.addAttribute("measuringUnits", CONSTANTS.MEASURING_UNITS);
            model.addAttribute("recipeOwner", users);
            return "createRecipe";
        }
        try {
            List<Image> imageRoutes = imageService.saveImages(recipeForm.getImageRoutes());
            List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
            for (RecipeForm.IngredientRow row : recipeForm.getIngredients()) {
                ingredients.add(new Ingredient(row.getName(), Double.parseDouble(row.getAmount()), row.getUnit()));
            }

            List<Instruction> instructions = new ArrayList<>();
            for (RecipeForm.InstructionRow row : recipeForm.getInstructions()) {
                instructions.add(new Instruction(row.getInstruction()));
            }

            List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();
            for (RecipeForm.TagRow row : recipeForm.getTags()) {
                tags.add(new Tag(row.getName()));
            }

            recipeService.save(new RecipeCreationEvent(
                    recipeForm.getTitle(),
                    recipeForm.getDescription(),
                    recipeForm.getServings(),
                    principal.getName(),
                    recipeForm.getRecipeOwner(),
                    imageRoutes,
                    tags,
                    ingredients,
                    instructions
            ));
            model.addAttribute("title", "Recipe Created!");
            model.addAttribute("message", "Recipe created successfully!");
            return "message";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "redirect:/recipe/createRecipe?error";
        }
    }
```

This is my test, which doesn't work, I am just unsure of how to create the necessary tests:

```
    @Test
    @WithMockUser
    @DisplayName("Creating a recipe")
    public void postRecipeForm() throws Exception {

        MockMultipartFile[] mockMultipartFiles = new MockMultipartFile[0];


        this.mockMvc
                .perform(multipart("/recipe/createRecipe")
                        .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
                        .param("title", "Recipe Title")
                        .param("description", "Recipe Description")
                        .param("servings", "12")
                        .param("recipeOwner", "john.smith@example.com")
                        .param("ingredients[0].name", "Ingredient 1")
                        .param("ingredients[0].amount", "12")
                        .param("ingredients[0].unit", "grams (g)")
                        .param("instructions[0].instruction", "Instruction 1")
                        .param("tags[0].name", "Tag 1")
                        .param("imageRoutes", Arrays.toString(mockMultipartFiles.toString().getBytes()))
                        .sessionAttr("recipe", new RecipeForm())
                )
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Recipe Created!")));
    }
```

Comment: looks like you are in a right track, however you can add  .file(imageFile) to your test in order to upload image.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a imageFile class with MockMultipartFile data type and call .file(imageFile) in your test method. do the same thing with multiple files.

```
MockMultipartFile imageFile = new MockMultipartFile(
        "imageRoutes",
        "image.jpg",
        MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE,
        "image data".getBytes()
);

this.mockMvc
        .perform(multipart("/recipe/createRecipe")
                .file(imageFile)
                .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
                .param("title", "Recipe Title")
                .param("description", "Recipe Description")
                .param("servings", "12")
                .param("recipeOwner", "john.smith@example.com")
                .param("ingredients[0].name", "Ingredient 1")
                .param("ingredients[0].amount", "12")
                .param("ingredients[0].unit", "grams (g)")
                .param("instructions[0].instruction", "Instruction 1")
                .param("tags[0].name", "Tag 1")
                .sessionAttr("recipe", new RecipeForm())
        )
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Recipe Created!")));
```